# Versionable text spreadsheet format, ideally with GUI editor

Tags: version-control, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a spreadsheet format that whose diffs won't look insane if I version it.

Ideally this would have a decent editor to go with it (GUI preferably), and should be available cross-platform, with Linux availability being essential. I'd also like it to preserve (at least basic) formatting if this is possible.

EDIT: It would need to support formulas in the source (ie, not the evaluated results).

Answer (score 0):

What all are you trying to do with your spreadsheets? Both `.xlsx` and `.ods` are pretty much just zipped XML files, so you could compare the diffs of the unzipped data (not pleasant, but doable). A csv or tab delimited file would work for simple data files. However, if you want to start using `diff` to see the difference between formulas and charts, you may consider using something like [R](http://www.r-project.org/), Python with [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) or [pyspread](http://pyspread.sourceforge.net) (I'm not 100% sure that the `.pys` format used by pyspread is human-readable).

There are also several [emacs spreadsheets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpreadSheet).

Answer (score 0):

most voted answer for similar question from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181522/139456):

> You can also use
>   libreOffice/open-office-spreadsheet-non-zip-xml-fileformat "*.fods"
>   which is plain xml.